# select only 1 row per customer id if the date is the same using rank (duplicate info)

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

```
created_at answer_id customer_id customer_name product email           score 

    20/09/2021  1502       abc1         Alex        watch  alex@gmail.com    10         
    20/09/2021  1502       def2         Alex        watch  alex@gmail.com    10
    22/08/2021  3405       ghi3         Ben         phone  ben@gmx.com        8
    22/08/2021  3405       jkl4         Ben         phone  ben@gmx.com        8
    12/09/2021  1439       abc1         Alex        tablet alex@gmail.com  10
```

I would like to ELIMINATE duplicate information, if the only difference being the customer_id.
However, if the answer_id and created_at are different, then it is no longer a duplicate information.

The query I have tried:

```
select * from (
select *,
rank() over ( partition by answer_id, customer_id order by created_at desc ) created_at_rank
from table ) rank_table
where rank = 1
```

Expected result:

```
created_at answer_id customer_id customer_name product email           score 
20/09/2021  1502       abc1         Alex        watch  alex@gmail.com    10         
22/08/2021  3405       ghi3         Ben         phone  ben@gmx.com        8
12/09/2021  1439       abc1         Alex        tablet alex@gmail.com  10
```

The second Alex result is included, because the record is generated on a different created date with a different answer id.

Comment: "I would like to select only 1 customer id from the table above." yet your expected results shows two, please clarify.

Comment: sorry. I mean 1 customer id per customer name.

Answer (score 0):

Try following query.

Need to use ROW_NUMBER() and based on your requirement you can order by column

```
select  created_at,answer_id,customer_id,customer_name,product,email,score  from (
select * from (
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY customer_name
       ORDER BY customer_id) AS RowNum,  created_at,answer_id,customer_id,customer_name,product,email,score 
from table 
) r where RowNum = 1
) report
```

Comment: hi, the query does not seem to generate the correct result when there are 3 rows with different dates, for example: abc1 has dates 19/05/2021, 25/08/2021, 20/09/2021. Because these are not duplicate information, I would like to keep all three. I only want to eliminate if there are identical information, with the only difference being the customer_id.

Comment: Okay. so you need to remove where condition RowNum = 1 and group by all required columns.

`select  created_at,answer_id,customer_id,customer_name,product,email,score  from (
select * from (
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY customer_name
       ORDER BY customer_id) AS RowNum,  created_at,answer_id,customer_id,customer_name,product,email,score 
from table 
) r
group by created_at,answer_id,customer_id,customer_name,product,email,score
) report`

Above query not tested only given an overview of how you achieve your result